# How can I run Bitnami OSQA with other web service (wordpress, joomla)?

Tags: php, python, django

I installed OSQA Bitnami on my VPS. And I also point 3 domains to this VPS. Now I want each domain point to different web service (I have another PHP website I want to host here).

How can I run php service along with OSQA Bitnami (it's python stack)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using apache virtual host you can point to different server port/applications in the same machine

> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.